# Passed dictionary class with segue fails when user update contents

Tags: ios, segue

My iOS app goes through a few tableviews to add data to a dictionary-based profile class.  When a user finishes the profile, the next login they can skip profile building (and those tableviews), but if they choose, they can rebuild their profile.  I use segues to pass the profile class forward, step-by-step.  On a rebuild, the app jumps back to the beginning.   PROBLEM: On a rebuild, the profile disappears when passed into the first tableview (Nationality).
Here's a bit of the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *sendArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:user0, nil];
NSLog(@"send array = %@", sendArray );
    if( buildPf ) {     //  to Nationality VC
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"getNationality"]) {
            Nationality_TableVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc.profiles0 = sendArray;
        }
    } else {        //  to Profile VC
        if( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"directToProfile"] ) {
            YourProfile_VC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc.profiles10 = sendArray;
            [vc setPushID:[user0.userID integerValue]];
            [vc setPushedPf:profileSum];
        }
    }
}
```

In the Nationality_VC, the .h:

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *profiles0;

In the .m:

```
@implementation Nationality_TableVC {
    NSUInteger  selectedIndex;
    NSUInteger  selectedRow;
    Profile     *user0;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    user0 = [[Profile alloc] init];
    user0 = [self.profiles0 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"(Nationality) user0 is %@", user0);
    selectedRow = -1;
    [self makeTableIndex];
}
```

Through debugging, I can see that the class is properly populated after the jump back.  The sendArray is always correct.  Through the same segue that worked during the initial build, the profile disappears.  Why?
The app crashes.  In the Nationality tableview, I have an NSLog.  During the initial build, the message is:

```
(Nationality) user0 is <Profile: 0x7152330>
```

During the rebuild, the message is:

```
(Nationality) user0 is (null)
```

Then trying to add the Nationality selection to a (null) profile, of course, causes the crash.
If the user chooses to Rebuild and then changes their mind they can, again, jump directly to the finished profile.  If they do, the segue correctly passes the profile class.  No problem.
What could cause the disappearance?

Comment: Besides being a weak coder, I'm also not great at stackoverflow questions.  How can I improve my questions?

Comment: You have a NSLog for `sendArray` but you don't say what it's showing you.

Comment: It shows the contents of the Profile class and is always right.

Comment: OK...is there anything inside `Nationality_TableVC` that changes the value of `profiles0` in any way?

Comment: No. It just gets the user0 from the segue.  Nothing else.  I'm using ARC, btw.  Could this be a memory issue?

Comment: Hard to say from what's there....  If `profiles0` is `weak`, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Phillip, but changing to weak also didn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry, no...I meant that if it's **already** weak that might explain it becoming null.  Otherwise, I think I ran out of ideas.  :)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, Nop, rescued me, again.  His debugging skills are much better than mine.  He showed me that my **buildPf** bool was actually blocking my prepareForSegue to Nationality_TableVC.  When the segue was called, it skipped the prepare.  In fact, the **buildPf** condition isn't needed at all in the prepareForSegue.  Wasted hours and hours on this stupid mistake.